# c# Linq to entities select case to a string

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have to query a list of entities and concatenate the results in a comma separated string, taking the consideration of a property of the entity.

I am using a foreach loop, but I am sure there is a better way using Linq

```
string str= string.Empty;
foreach (var item in grupos)
{
    if (item.BLOCKED)
        str+= "," + item.ID_BLOCKED;
    else
        str+= "," + item.ID;
 }
 str= str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

let me know if this works for you

```
string str= string
         .Join(",", grupos.Select(x => x.BLOCKED? x.ID_BLOCKED.ToString() : x.GRP_ID.ToString())
         .ToArray());
```